# Matlab S-function builder with Visual Studio 2013 - missing rtwtypes.h

Tags: c, matlab, visual-studio-2013, simulink, s-function

I'm trying to compile pre-generated code from Simulink S-function builder and I get an error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'rtwtypes.h': No such file or directory
```

I've gone trough every include directory in matlab and simulink and there is no such header file. I'm using Matlab 2014b. What may be the problem?

BTW. I can compile MEX files without any problems.

[image: My %MATLAB_ROOT%\extern\include folder]

I tried including "hacked" file found on network:
[Header rtwtypes.h source](http://web.anglia.ac.uk/mpa/ref/th/Hall2011a_Dialects/Ch%2023%20Dialects/extensions_c23_dialects/ENIAC/Eniac_Cycling%20Source%20Code/rtwtypes.h)

But it doesn't work as well as I expected, now my error is:

```
fatal error C1189: #error :  Must define one of RT, NRT, MATLAB_MEX_FILE, SL_INTERNAL, or FIPXT_SHARED_MODULE
```

Comment: It's in MATLABROOT\extern.

Comment: It isn't. At least not for me. At least not in MATLABROOT\extern\include and not in the MATLABROOT\extern\lib.

Comment: That's strange, because it's been in MATABROOT/extern/include for many, many releases, and that's where the doc says it is:[Templates for C S-Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/templates-for-c-s-functions.html).

Comment: I believe you have mistaken rtwtypes.h (which I'm missing) with tmwtypes.h.

 Besides MATLABROOT\extern\include directory is already included in my project.

Comment: I've included my include directory files in case you still wont believe me xD

Comment: Sorry, I was fixated on tmwtypes.h not rtwtypes.h, but see my comment to your anwer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why rtwtypes.h isn't in matlab or simulink include directory...
But solution for my problem was:

1. Include [found on network rtwtypes.h](http://web.anglia.ac.uk/mpa/ref/th/Hall2011a_Dialects/Ch%2023%20Dialects/extensions_c23_dialects/ENIAC/Eniac_Cycling%20Source%20Code/rtwtypes.h) file into project
2. Add line above `#define S_FUNCTION_LEVEL 2` in your **your-s-function-name.c**:

`#define MATLAB_MEX_FILE`

It builds without problem. Does it work as good as standard sfunction compiled by Matlab? I have no idea, some test may be needed.

Comment: Thanks for help. For some reason rtwtypes.h isnt generated in my project. Is it possible to set it in preferences (or somewhere else)?

Comment: If required, then rtwtypes.h is a file that is autogenerated during the build process, and should be in the same directory as the auto-generated source code.

Comment: Your fix is a bit of a hack, which means the code will only compile for desktop simulation, not for any potential real-time use, which may not be a problem for you.  If it is, then you'll need to try to figure out why the file isn't generated, but the code expects it to be.